# Is there any way to get project level error/warning messages from Team Build 2010 without slowing the build down?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am in the process of setting up continuous integration in our TFS system.  One major part of our system are the development of about 50 DotNetNuke modules to support our CMS infrastructure.  Right now, each of those projects have their own solution since their code bases are mostly siloed (with common code in 1 or 2 common projects).  Keeping them in their own solution is done because it makes the development process faster (loading, compiling, etc....)

However, this has proven difficult to maintain when setting up TFS team build as each solution has to be manually added to the build definition and MSBuild seems unable to take advantage of parallel compiling due to each project being in its own solution.  This causes about 5 minute full build times, which while isn't horrible isn't ideal.  Mostly though, it's not ideal from a build definition maintenance aspect.

To solve this I creating a global solution that included all projects.  The idea being that if you want your project to be automatically compiled and deployed by TFS you will have to include your project in the global solution.  This seems works well, as it's easy to maintain from a build definition standpoint and brings the total build time down to 70 seconds.

The one problem is that the displayed TFS build log groups all warnings and errors together under the solution instead of separating them out by project.  This makes it difficult to quickly see what project caused which errors and warnings.

Is there a good way to see project level error/warning messages in the build log summary view without delving into the cluttered build log?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your direct question, I believe the answer is no (at least not without some heavy customization).

For me this is never a big concern as I am pretty aggressive about getting my teams to bring errors/warnings down to zero, then enforcing it via TFS Build (/p:TreatWarningsAsErrors=true).  This means you should never have to wade through hundreds of warnings in the build summary.

If you add all your individual solutions to the build definition, you can always use the TFS Power Tools to "clone" a build def to make maintenance easier.  You could also modify the Build Template to build the solutions/projects in parallel, although this runs the risk of having file contention issues.